# C++ Windows Form, cannot restart timer on UDP server

Tags: c++, timer, udp

I have a UDP server. I need to close the UDP connection when the server doesn't receive anything for 5 minutes. In order to do this I am using a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. The problem appears when I try to restart the timer. I found the following code about how to restart a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` but in my case this doesn't work.

```
    timer -> Stop();
    timer -> Start();
```

When the server starts, if it doesn't receive anything then the timer ticks the event. If the server receives something then the timer never ticks the event when the time interval passed. Below is my code:

```
    public ref class UDP_Server : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        delegate void ShowMessageMethod(String^ msg);
        ShowMessageMethod^  ShMsgMeth;
        UdpClient^          server; 
        IPEndPoint^         serverEnd;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnClose;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Timer^  UDPTimer;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox^  richTextBox1;
    private: System::ComponentModel::IContainer^  components;
    public:
        UDP_Server(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            UDPTimer = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Timer();
            UDPTimer -> Interval = 300000; // miliseconds
            UDPTimer -> Tick += gcnew EventHandler(this, &HVLV_PS::UDP_Server::UDPTimer_Tick);
        }
//load the main window consisting of a richTextBox1 and btnClose
    private: System::Void UDP_Server_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
    {
        ShMsgMeth = gcnew ShowMessageMethod(this, &UDP_Server::ShowMsg);
        UDPTimer -> Start();
        ReceiveMessage();
    }
    public: void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult^ asyncResult)
    {
        ASCIIEncoding^ ascii = gcnew ASCIIEncoding;
        try
        {
            array^ data = server -> EndReceive(asyncResult, serverEnd);
            if (data->Length > 0)
            {
                String^ receivedMsg = ascii -> GetString(data, 0, data->Length);
                this->BeginInvoke(ShMsgMeth, gcnew array{"Client:" + receivedMsg});
                TimerReset(UDPTimer);
            }
                server -> BeginReceive(gcnew AsyncCallback(this, &HVLV_PS::UDP_Server::ReceiveCallback), nullptr);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException^ e)
        {
            return; // udp connection closed
        }
    }
    private: void ReceiveMessage()
    {
        IPAddress^ hostIPAddress = IPAddress::Parse( "127.0.0.1" ); 
        serverEnd = gcnew IPEndPoint(hostIPAddress, 16000); 
        server = gcnew UdpClient(serverEnd); 
        server -> BeginReceive(gcnew AsyncCallback(this, &HVLV_PS::UDP_Server::ReceiveCallback), nullptr);
    }
    private: void ShowMsg(String^ msg)
    {
        richTextBox1->Text += msg + "\r\n";
    }
    private: System::Void btnClose_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
    {
        server->Close();
        UDPTimer -> Stop();
        UDP_Server::Close();
    }
    private: System::Void UDPTimer_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
        {
            UDPTimer -> Stop();     // the timer stops,
            server->Close();        // the udp connection closes
            Close();                // the main window of the server closes 
        }
    public: void TimerReset(System::Windows::Forms::Timer^ timer)
        {
            timer -> Stop();
            timer -> Start();
        }
    };
```

Comment: the UDPTimer is a member of a class why does that need to be passed to `TimerReset`. The function could simply be public: void `TimerReset()
        {
            UDPTimer -> Stop();
            UDPTimer -> Start();
        } `

Comment: @Samer Tufail: I have tried this but it doesn't work either.

Comment: It wasnt meant to make it to work, just a comment on passing member variables around :)